# Delay message consumption with SelectConnection

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitmq, pika

I want to write a consumer with a SelectConnection.

We have several devices in our network infrastructure that close connections after a certain time, therefore I want to use the heartbeat functionality.

As far as I know, the IOLoop runs on the main thread, so heartbeat frames can not be processed while this thread is processing the message.

My idea is to create several worker threads that process the messages so that the main thread can handle the IOLoop. The processing of a message takes a lot of resources, so only a certain amount of the messages should be processed at once. Instead of storing the remaining messages on the client side, I would like to leave them in the queue.

Is there a way to interrupt the consumption of messages, without interrupting the heartbeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert on SelectConnection for pika, but you could implement this by setting the [Consumer Prefetch (QoS)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) to the wanted number of processes.

This would basically mean that once a message comes in, you offload it to a process or thread, once the message has been processed you then acknowledge that the message has been processed.

As an example, if you set the QoS to 10. The client would pull at most 10 messages, and won't pull any new messages until at least one of those has been acknowledged.

The important part here is that you would need to acknowledge messages only once you are finished processing them.